I am facing a problem of MongoDB Shell Connection Failure when I command `mongosh` in linux zorin
I am using linux zorin os. Recently I installed mongoDB in my system using these commands :

For import the Public Key : curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg

For Creating the Source List : echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list

For updating the Package Database : sudo apt update

For starting the MongoDB Service : sudo systemctl start mongod

For enable MongoDB to Start on Boot : sudo systemctl enable mongod

For enabling MongoDB to Start on Boot : sudo systemctl enable mongod


But I am facing the problem : 
I have used online contents and chatgpt but i can not find any solution. After running mongosh command, MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 error occurred. I used online contents and chatgpt but failed to solve the problem.

try without directConnection and make sure that server is launched

Most likely your mongod service does not run. sudo systemctl enable mongod only enables it, but does not start it. Check the mongod log file, typically /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
